# Maintain size of integral sign with limits

Tags: front-end, formatting, cells, traditional-form

In a text cell, I am trying to typeset an integral.

Notice the large size of the integral sign in this example:

[image: integral no limits]

But as soon as I try to include limits of integration next to the integral sign, the size of the integral sign becomes smaller:

[image]

How do I maintain the original size of the integral sign, even after including the limits?

An answer where I have to directly edit the cell expression using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> on PC) is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt this is the best way, but one way is to

- wrap the integrand with `Style[_, ScriptLevel -> 1]`
- wrap the whole expression with `Style[HoldForm[_], ScriptLevel -> 0]`
- use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↩</kbd> (or equivalently Evaluation > Evaluate in Place)

[image]

[image]

Comment: This will work, but in the last step, ⌘+⇧+E just goes to cell expression mode. What shortcut did you use after highlighting the entire expression?

Comment: @ChipHurst I am more interested in how you captured your typing. Could you share?

Comment: @QuantumDot Sorry, I had a typo. I used ⌘+↩.

Comment: @JackLaVigne I used [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/).